# PHP: Any logical use cases for include/requiring remote source files?

Tags: php, security

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php

The only time I could ever think of doing include("http://someotherserver/foo.php") would be as some sort of weird intra-server service interface, but even then I could think of a million different ways that were safer to accomplish the same thing.   Still, my specific question is, has anyone seen remote includes in a production environment and did it make any sense doing so?

Edit:
   To clear something up, I would cause physical injury to befall anyone who ever tried to use remote includes in a production environment I worked on... So yes I know this is a nightmarish security hole.  Just trying to figure out why its still there versus other weird ideas like magic quotes and global variables.

Comment: Looking at http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=include\%28\%22http%3A%2F%2F+lang%3Aphp&sbtn=Search, I cannot see a single logical use.

Comment: @Paul Biggar Remote includes seems more fatal an idea then Global Variables... but unlike Global variables Remote includes still exist?

Comment: a side effect of fopen wrappers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I've never seen this in real life, I could imagine a farm with separate physical servers with no shared file system. You could possibly have one server with the all the code ie api.domain.com and the other servers include from it. It would make deployments easier if you have tens or hundreds of sepearate sites. But as alex said, it's asking to be hacked.

Comment: I didn't think of that and your idea sounds like one of the only sane reasons to use remote includes.

Comment: This is something I've thought of (but actually implementing this would be way to risky for me).

Answer (score 1):

Remote file execution is extremely dangerous... I've never used it on my servers, and I can't imagine a valid reason to put your, ahem, balls into the basket that someone else controls. That's just asking to be hacked.

Comment: But have you ever seen it used by anyone?

Comment: Even if the code was on another server *you* controlled, anything over the public internet is a little crazy. Maybe more than a little.

Answer (score 0):

**No, I didn't.** It's going to the bear's mouth.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the possiblity to include/require remote files is a consequence of [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) -- which was introduced in PHP 4.0.x.

Though, considering the security risks of remote-inclusion, a new directive, [`allow_url_include`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) was introduced in PHP 5.2 : now, this one determines whether you can remote include/require, while the first ones only impacts fopen and the like -- which is nice : it allows an admin to disable remote inclusion, while keeping remote opening.

As others, I didn't ever see remote-require/include used in real-case scenario, while I, of course, often see situations where remote-opening is used -- bad thing is I sometimes see servers with `allow_url_fopen` disabled because of security reasons that don't exist anymore :-(